# Gazebo-11, Get forces in joint in current step

Tags: joint, gazebo-11, physics

I have a model plugin that read the joint wrench (GetForceTorque) and update it beforePhysicsUpdate. But I realize that the GetForceTorque, called in beforePhysicsUpdate, provides the resultant wrench of the previous step simulation.

E.g. By adding a force to a link, performing a step and getting the wrench in the joint during the beforePhysicsUpdate, the force is not present, but it will be in the next step.

Does the wrench of the Joints transmitted from a connected link is computed in the Collision phase (which should be available on the beforePhysicsUpdate) or they are indeed computed in the physicsUpdate? Is there a way to edit the forces of the current step in the joints before the PhysicsUpdate?